# Setting innerHTML eats inner form element. Since when and by what browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, chromium

If the following code were to run as I expected, pressing the button would replace the inner P element of the FORM into another FORM and a nested border would appear:

```
<form id="aa1" style="border: solid 2px blue; padding: 4px;">
    <p>Original content</p>
</form>

<button type="button"
 onclick="document.getElementById('aa1').innerHTML = '<form id=\'aa2\' style=\'border: solid 8px red; padding: 4px;\'><p>New content</p></form>';">
 Click me
</button>
```

In Chrome 119 and Edge 118 (on Windows) this is not what is happening: the inner form is stripped out and the original paragraph gets replaced by the content of the inner form.

I know, nested forms are not allowed in HTML.

**My question is**: are all browsers behaving like this ? Is this behaviour described somewhere ? Since what versions are browsers behaving like this ?

Try it on Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rnk9vms5/3/

Comment: I have a VM running WS 2012 R2 with IE11 still working and IE11 also replaces the entire `<form>`: https://imgur.com/a/CpdegPx - so this certainly isn't new behaviour (as IE11 came out in October 2013, 10 years ago)

Comment: when you hav invalid HTML, the browser tries to figure out a way to make it work. How the browser fixes the bug in your code is up to the browser.

Comment: @epascarello: hence my question: which browsers behave in what way ? Is that really at the sole discretion of the browser, or is this "corrective" behaviour documented and versioned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers are very lenient and accept invalid HTML, trying to render it anyway and making assumptions about what the programmer may have wanted. This does not mean that you should rely on such behavior or write invalid HTML on purpose.

> are all browsers behaving like this?

Yes, all of them nowadays.

> Is this behaviour described somewhere? Since what versions are browsers behaving like this?

Not really. It is implementation specific and will vary from browser to browser, and likely also from version to version of the same browser. You should not rely on it.

---

As an example, a web page containing the following invalid HTML code:

```html
<a>Hello
```

Will be transformed by most modern browsers to:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a>Hello</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Then why trying to create something that is invalid HTML?" > 
You should bear in mind that in my question I express a specific situation but that my code may be more generic. I'm not trying to nest HTML forms. I'm trying to replace innerHTML. It is generic functionality and I do not have in control who is going to use it for what...

Comment: @codetuner updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your update. I upvoted now as it now answers my question. However note that not closing the P tag is not invalid on all HTML versions: it was not in the original HTML spec (see note 1i on https://shorturl.at/EHLRV) and seem still not to be absolutely required (see Tag omission in https://shorturl.at/uAJVW). For the rest, you are right, browsers are lenient. The difference here is that the browser is not just lenient in rendering nested forms but effectively manipulates the injected HTML to remove parts of it. Thanks for your answers and your time!

Comment: @codetuner *"The difference here is that the browser is not just lenient in rendering nested forms but effectively manipulates the injected HTML to remove parts of it."* - yes exactly! Sometimes this can also happen in very surprising ways. For example, security-wise there have been cases where attackers purposefully inject malformed HTML to bypass XSS filters that will then be rendered functional by the browser trying to "fix" things. It's pretty fun. See e.g. [this page](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html). P.S. edited `<p>` to `<a>`.